# how can i get the date in "Month Year" format?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently using this piece of code to get month and year.

```
CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(year, StartDate)) + '-' +  RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(month, StartDate)), 2) As Month
```

but it returns "2011-06"

My Startdate format = 2011-06-15 14:03:00

I would like to get this into "June 2011" - how can I do that?

Comment: See this compilation of date conversions: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx (first hit on searching for `sql server date formatting` in Google)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, getdate()) + ' ' + DATENAME(year, getdate())
```